# Splitting and combining two arrays Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

i have an array with recurring values like

```
{1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12}
```

and another array with data

```
{itema
itemb
itemc
itemd}
```

i wan to split the first array and then to combine with second array that my output looks like ..

```
{
itema=>1,5,9
itemb=>2,6,10
itemc=>3,7,11
itemd=>4,8,12
}
```

i want to group the elements of array . Basically they are obtained using xpath and 4 values combine together to become information about a single subject. My basic purpose is to modify first array such that i can print values of same domain together...I want to print

> 1,2,3,4,
>
> 5,6,7,8
>
> 9, 10,11, 12

Question might look strange, but i am struggling to describ it completely...Sorry for that

Comment: changed the code for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first array you talk of is a multi dimensional array, as in

```
$firstArray = { a={1,2,3},b={1,2,3} };
```

What you need to do is loop through each array and create a new one in the process.

```
$masterArray = {itema,itemb,itemc,itemd};


$newArray = new Array();
for ($i = 0; $i<$masterArray.length; $i++) {
   for ($j = 0; $j<$firstArray.length; $j++){
      $newArray[$i] = $masterArray[$i]=>$firstArray[$j][$i];
   }
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

I haven't tested the code myself, so I can't say it's perfect, but that's basically what you want to do.
Feel free to ask questions.

Edit: As a result of a discussion, I found out that using the array chunk function did what the OP wanted, but not what the question asked.

Comment: Man its not multi-dimentional...only each four elements cab be group together as each four consective elements are information about the same thing

Comment: I'm not totally sure what that means. Can you var_dump the array variables you are using please, as it's not clear exactly how they are built.

Comment: in simple words, i have array of elements, i want to create another array. The newArray will combine first four consective elemets into first element of NewArray, then 2nd 4 elements to 2nd element of NewAray and so on

Comment: What do you mean, "elements"? How you do this depends on exactly what is in the array. As you say it's not in a multi-dimentional array, it might be easier to first PUT them into a multi-dimentional array.

Comment: 1a, 1b, 1c, 1d, 2a, 2b, 2c,... all are elements of first array ..and i need to group up them...

Comment: The first array in your question is unclear. Is it 3 groups of 3?, Why is there a space? Is the space part of the array? {a1,a2,a3,,b1,b2,b3} ? Showing us a var_dump of the arrays will help. Also for the output, from the looks of it you want it to be a multi-dimentinal array, in which case it should look like {"itema"=>{a1,b1,c1}}

Comment: so you need your to go from that array to an array which is 1=>1a,2a,3a etc?

Comment: right ok. Do you know how many elements will be in the first array?

Comment: nay, but onething is sure, it will be 4x,however, using count() or length(), it can be known

Comment: Looking at the required output, you just want to print out the array in chunks of 4 elements at a time? correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7592/discussion-between-n-e-w-b-e-e-and-relequestual)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
$b = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
$aLength = count($a);
$bLength = count($b);
$c = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $bLength; ++$i) {
    $c[$b[$i]] = array();
    $j = $i;
    while ($j < $aLength) {
        $c[$b[$i]][] = $a[$j];
        $j += $bLength;
    }
}
var_dump($c);
```